# Fedora 31 kernels 5.5.10 and 5.5.11 fail when trying to decrypt luks root filesystem after kernel update, but kernel 5.5.8 works

Tags: fedora, systemd, kernel, luks, cryptsetup

After updating to kernel 5.5.10-200.fc31, Fedora 31 can't decrypt the root file system on boot. After entering the decryption passphrase, the filesystem fails to decrypt. The same happens with kernel 5.5.11. However, if I boot with kernel 5.5.8 there's no problem. These are the error messages I get with 5.5.11 when running 'journalctl':

```
localhost.localdomain systemd-cryptsetup[436]: device-mapper: reload ioctl on   failed: Invalid argument
localhost.localdomain kernel: device-mapper: table: 253:0: crypt: unknown target type
localhost.localdomain kernel: device-mapper: ioctl: error adding target to table
localhost.localdomain systemd-cryptsetup[436]: Failed to activate with specified passphrase: Invalid argument
localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: systemd-cryptsetup@luks\.... .service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: systemd-cryptsetup@luks\.... .service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start cryptography setup for luks-....
localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Local Encrypted Volumes.
localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Job cryptsetup.target/start failed with result 'dependency'
```

I left out the luks ids as I'm typing this up by hand.
Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should head over to https://bugzilla.redhat.com and report this as a bug. It is very unlikely that we here can help.

Only advise (for now) is to delete the oldest offending kernel(s), so you only keep the very last one and one (or two) working kernels, that way an update won't erase a working kernel.

Comment: Thankyou, I'll do that. Good point about removing the deleting older kernels that aren't working. I'll keep the newest in case there's a chance to repair the problem,

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else running into this problem - I was able to solve it by:

1. Booting into a working kernel, and removing all software which had been installed from standalone rpm files.
2. (While still booted from the older working kernel) regenerating initramfs for the latest kernel using dracut, in my case this was for 5.5.11:

   sudo dracut /boot/initramfs-5.5.11-200.fc31.x86_64.img 5.5.11-200.fc31.x86_64